# MVC ViewModel null values in POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am fairly new to MVC and I have run into a problem persisting values on the page POST. Below is a simplified version of what I am trying to do. Basically I have a form where I display the users name and other details. On the POST ActionResult if the business rules fail the page should return to the current view else will proceed on but on my POST the name and address I set in the GET do not appear in the POST for the view model resulting in null values being sent back in the return View(model). Are there ways I can persists the values without having go back to the database to retrieve them?

Model

```
public class HomeModel
{
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public bool Continue { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new HomeModel();
    model.Forename = "Joe";
    model.Surname = "Boe";
    model.AddressLine1 = "Unknown";

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HomeModel homeModel)
{
    if (homeModel.Continue)
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Form2");
   else
        return View(homeModel);
}
```

View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Forename, Model.Forename)<br />
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Surname, Model.Surname)<br />
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddressLine1, Model.AddressLine1)<br /><br />
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Continue)<br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Click" />
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hidden field:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
```

This will then post the value back to the server. This will increase your data amounts for the post, and for large forms is inadvisable.

That said, you are probably better off rebuilding the data for the page load or doing server side caching, as otherwise you run the risk of injections of bad data. That may not matter to you if it is read only though.

Comment: I think the caching idea may be the route I will take.

Answer (score 3):

`LabelFor` doesn't create an HTML `input` type, so it's not included in the postback.  You can make them `TextBoxFor`s or, create `HiddenFor`s alongside your labels so they persist back to the server

Comment: I probably don't want to store a long list of hidden elements on the view